# Override print method in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, overriding

I have a (syntax?) question about an overrided toString method and the get method for Array Lists.

My first class titled BAccount creates an object that contains a name, balance, and account number.

```
public class BAccount { 
private static int lastAssignedNumber=1000;
String uName;
double uBalance;
private int accountNumber;
public BAccount(String name, double balance) {
    uName=name;
    lastAssignedNumber++;
    uBalance=balance;
    accountNumber=lastAssignedNumber;
}

public void setName(String inputName) { 
    uName=inputName;
}

public void setBalance(double inputBalance) {
    uBalance=inputBalance;
}

public String getName() {
    return uName;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return uBalance;
}

public int getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public String toString() { 
    return ("Account Holder Name: " + this.getName() +
            ", Acccount Balance: " + this.getBalance() +
            ", Account Number: " + this.getAccountNumber());
}
```

My tester class creates 3 accounts,adds them to an ArrayList and prints each using the get method.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test { 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<BAccount> accountArray=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { 
    System.out.print("Enter Account Holder Name: ");
    String name=in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Account Balance: ");
    double balance=in.nextDouble();
    in.nextLine();
    BAccount account= new BAccount(name, balance);
    accountArray.add(account);
    }
    System.out.println(accountArray.get(0));
    System.out.println(accountArray.get(1));
    System.out.println(accountArray.get(2));
}
```

}

The tester class creates 3 accounts,adds them to an ArrayList and prints each using the get method.

**My question is**: How does the ArrayList's get method know to use my  override toString method's format for printing?

Comment: `PrintStream.println(Object);` invokes `Object.toString()` - which you have overridden.

Comment: ... as the javadoc explains clearly.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList.get() doesn't know about that!

This method simply returns a reference to the object stored at the index given to get().

It is the println() that in the end calls toString() on that object. And in Java, the exact version of the method to call is derived from the exact type of the object - dynamically at runtime. That is called *polymorphism* and simply a cornerstone of OO programming.

That object is an instance of your class that has overriden toString()... leading to the desired and fully expected results.